# How to edit topbar HTML in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using this theme http://demo.themeum.com/wordpress/educon/ 
And need to edit red topbar so it looks like image[image: See here]

I tried to edit it in Walker_Nav_Menu class but I couldn't find code for topbar. I need the guidance of which file I need to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually in Wordpress themes the nav menu is created dynamically, settings to be found in the backend `Design > Menus`

But the CSS (i.e. the styling) for it usually is in the `style.css` file. Just check that nav bar with the browser tools to find which rules are applied and search for them / modyfy them / overwrite them in the stylesheet or (in case of overwriting)  in your own additional CSS (for example in the customizer or in the `style.css` file of your child theme, if you have created one)

Comment: There are no useful options for topbar in theme. I know I can add custom CSS, but I need to edit HTML too. The reason is that design I got uses different column grid than theme.

Comment: I am not talking aout theme options, but about the CSS. Concerning HTML, the menu inclusion will usually happen in the `header.php` or `sidebar.php` file, with a WP template tag similar to `wp_nav_menu()` . You won't find the menu entries themselves there, but the HTML around the menu

Comment: Thank you. The answer was helpful. Now, after looking at header.php I found that HTML for topbar is located in /lib/topbar.php. How smart is to edit this?

Comment: Depends on how much you know about HTML and PHP... Make a backup of the file and try to make changes. If you end up in chaos, replace the edited file with the backup...

Comment: I will do as you said. Backup first. I am OK with HTML but zero with PHP. Thank you very much.